# How do I set the filename of a module in Python so that exceptions that occur in the module use that filename?

Tags: python, string, python-import, python-module

I'm importing modules from strings (don't ask) using the `imp` library. This is all working fine and dandy, but when there's an error in such a module, I get a stacktrace like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 33, in do_something
  File "<string>", line 20, in really_do_something
Exception: STRING FILENAME EXAMPLE
```

I've tried setting the **file** attribute on the module to something that makes sense, but the `<string>` filename is still used in the exception traceback.

Any ideas on how to specify the filename used in the exception?

UPDATE: I'm using imp like this: [Dynamic module importing is trying to do relative imports when it shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862562/python-dynamic-module-importing-is-trying-to-do-relative-imports-when-it-shoul)

Comment: Can you show the code where you import the module using `imp`?

Comment: The filename is taken from the code object(s), not the module object. We'll need to see how you compile the string.

Comment: k, added a link to how I'm using the imp module

Comment: It looks like `imp.new_module` returns a new (empty) module.  Then you populate it with `exec`.  It seems like it would be easier  to re-work your logic so that you use `imp.load_module` instead...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filename is set in the code objects produced by `exec()`. Instead of using `exec()` with a string, you should use [`compile()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#compile) to compile your code separately. That way you can set the filename:

```
code = compile(file_contents, '/your/filename.py', 'exec')
exec(code, mod.__dict__)
```

Comment: `vars(mod)` is an alternative to `mod.__dict__`.