# How to give exec code meaningful location to show if exception?

Tags: python

The code given to `exec` below will pass without compile errors, but will result in an run-time error at "error" statement:

```
globs = {}

exec('''
def main():
    print('Hello Python')
    error  # Makes run-time error
''', globs)

globs['main']()
```

The error message is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "C:\work\sandbox.py", line 11, in 
        globs['main']()
      File "<string>", line 4, in main
    NameError: name 'error' is not defined
```

The location information of only `File "<string>", line 4, in main` is not very useful, for example when trying the locate the origin of the code which can be from a file.

Note that the above is a simplified example to show the issue.  In the actual program the code defines several functions that are executed at different locations in the main program.

Is there some way to provide the code from `exec` with another location than "<string>", so this other location is shown if an exception occurs in the exec code?

Comment: If someone can give me a use case for `exec(...)` in Python, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure the duplicate actually answers this question, which seems to be about passing something more useful than "<string>" as source for the code executed by `exec`.

Comment: I reopened because the duplicate question is not the same (it asks how to get the "line 4" in code).

Comment: @interjay (and AndreLaszlo comment): Thanks for reopening, since the duplicate handles the case where `exec` itself causes the exception, but this is not the case in this question, since the exception does not occur until later when a function in the `exec` code is called

Comment: Related question: [python - File "<string>" traceback with line preview - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183305/file-string-traceback-with-line-preview). If the code does come from a physical *source file* then it helps, but otherwise not really.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the filename of a module in Python so that exceptions that occur in the module use that filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977578/how-do-i-set-the-filename-of-a-module-in-python-so-that-exceptions-that-occur-in)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile) your code and give it a filename argument:

```
code = compile('error', 'foo.py', 'exec')
exec(code)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "foo.py", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'error' is not defined
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it :-)  Btw. is there some way to specify a line-number offset, for use if the compiled code does not start at line 1 in the source file ?

Comment: The only way I could come up with is quite an ugly hack: `code = compile(('\n' * 99) + 'error', 'foo.py', 'exec')`. That would give you the same error but on line 100 :) I tried setting the `co_firstlineno` property of the code  but it's read-only just like `co_filename`.

Comment: Not pretty, but I think it will do the job and is robust. Thanks :-D

Answer (score 0):

Write the code you're `exec`ing to a file, and [run it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script).

Or better still, accept code input from a file *in the first place*. This is potentially more secure and makes the code more easily auditable. It also makes it easier for the user to change it later, if that feature is desired.

You should avoid using `exec` for code you don't control - it's extremely dangerous. Unless you're writing  procedurally generated code, there's no reason for using it.

Comment: The code defines a number of functions that can be called later, and allows users to easily extend a main Python program.  The code given to `exec` is no different from the main Python program; just gives a way to extend the program in a easy way, so I don't think this make the use of `exec` "dangerous".

Comment: Thanks for the update, and good point about not using `exec` to let in 3rd party uncontrolled code.

Comment: @EquipDev You're absolutely right. If you're absolutely sure that you're executing code provided by the user, `exec` is safe. The problem is not as much with `exec` as it is in getting code from the user; that's the part that's different from your main python program - the mechanism for obtaining the code. This is also why using files is a better idea.

Comment: Another reason is to read the code from a file, and then preprocess the code; one type of preprocessing might even analyze the code for dangerous behavior, but a more common type of preprocessing would be macro expansion, another would be decompression.